# How to check whether the android device is connected to a Bluetooth mouse?

Tags: android, android-hardware

When my application starting, I want to check whether the android device is connected to a Bluetooth mouse, and listening to the connected event.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Android Bluetooth APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), you can get a list of connected devices like so:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

There's no good way to tell what type of device is connected, but you can run through the devices and their names by iterating through the `pairedDevices` Set. The Android Bluetooth Guide has a lot more details on Bluetooth.